# Deleting Git repo can no longer clone because repo still exists

Tags: git, repository

I was cloning my bitbucket repo onto my student website using visual studio code, when i accidentally cloned it outside of my public_html. (I wanted it in public_html) So I rm -fr  git to delete the repo and re clone it inside public_html. But the repo names still showed and I was unable to clone because it said that the repo already exists. I tried git status and it said that there was an error because the repo doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Go in your desired path where you want to put the cloned repo, then try `git clone ##link ##folder_name` where ##link is your https:// link of online repository and ##folder_name the name you could specify for the folder where you want put the cloned repository (##folder_name is not mandatory, but it can be done for test).